# "OperationalError : no password supplied", when linking python and sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pycharm, psycopg2

I just learned how to use sqlalchemy in python to link sql
but when I tried it myself, I repeatedly faced with an error code.

Tried to find out what's wrong, but I couldn't.
The professor told me that there's something wrong with my datatype when declaring class,
but I cannot find out what's wrong with it.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('postgresql://ccp.zjarotlf@147.46.197.124:56416/ccp?sslmode=disable')
Base = declarative_base()

class Tradingitem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tradingitem'
    tradingitemid = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    tickersymbol = Column(String)
    companyname = Column(String)
    streetaddress = Column(String)
    streetaddress = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    zipcode = Column(String)
    officephonevalue = Column(String)
    exchangename = Column(String)
    isocode = Column(String)


Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = Session()

query = session.query(Tradingitem).filter(Tradingitem.tradingitemid.in_(['2638938']))

result = query.all()
```

This is what my code looks like.
and this is the error code :

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
> fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Looking forward for your help!

Comment: its  asking for db password  put the password without  {}. postgresql://ccp.zjarotlf:{password}@147.46.197.124:56416/ccp?sslmode=disable

Comment: wow it worked seriously I'm sure you are an angel without wings you saved me from hours of stress lol :)